# MP2617H(PMIC) is not working

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, pmic

I am designing a PCB board for our vehicle tracking device. Here the device will track GPS location and send it to the user.
This is a battery operated device.
Our power station provides us 12v input voltage and by using this we want to charge our device and operate as well in the same tim[image]e.
I am using here MP2617H (MP2617HGL-P) PMIC battery charger with power path management for single-cell Li-ion.
When I give 12V input to our circuit, I expect to get 4.2v at Vsys PIN and battery should be charged too at the same time but I get 0V at Vsys Pin and same as on battery connection point.

Here I am attaching a schematic and layout file of that.
Please help me into find out exact problem.

Comment: Can you post a schematic with a higher resolution? Most labels are unreadable.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Please draw ground pointing down in the future. Do you have a battery connected? Is the circuit trying to do something but senses no battery/something else and stops?